# My system is not shutting down after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS!

Tags: shutdown, 16.04

I was using Ubuntu 15.10 and everything was working fine. But yesterday I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and now its not shutting down. I have to plug away my battery to turn it off and also the battery indicator is not working!

Comment: Ok, just to make sure, are you shutting down by clicking the right corner button and pressing shutdown right?

Comment: Does the computer shut down when you run `sudo shutdown`? If not, what's the output of that command and what's at the end of the output of `sudo dmesg` after you issued the first command?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your shutdown log, you will most-likely see a line which says "plymouthd has been excluded from killing..."

Redhat already has a note on this function in their bugs report. It appears related to Fedora. Everyone is offering band-aids to this, at this time, but even if you take ownership from root for plymouthd or go to a non-splash shutdown, it appears not to stop the problem. The problem is very persistent (for whatever reason) on Dell and HP computers, too. (I can't get a single Dell laptop to shutdown by proper shutdown command, after Ubuntu 16.04LTS is installed).

This should be considered a MAJOR bug, due to the ramifications to hardware as a result of doing the old 'hold the power button for 8-10 seconds' process.
The problem resides in plymouthd being excluded from being killed. Who in their right mind protects a SPLASH SCREEN on exit, so that it can't be killed, so that the harddrive can't be remounted in ro mode, so that logoff can be successfully conducted?

Comment: I got the same issue too on my hp laptop, had to force shutdown every time by pressing the power button for 10 sec.